maven for packaging type ear, is maven-ear-plugin optional in pom.xml
In my pom.xml, the packaging is ear
<packaging>ear</packaging>

it has dependency on a war
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xxx</groupId>
        <artifactId>abc</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>    
  </dependencies>

and it has plugins for maven-ear-plugin
<plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <modules>
           <webModule>
              <groupId>xxx</groupId>
              <artifactId>abc</artifactId>
              <uri>abc-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war</uri>
              <contextRoot>/abc</contextRoot>
            </webModule>          
          </modules>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>

but I try to comment out the  section for maven-ear-plugin, the ear is still built succesfully with the war inside, so is the  section of maven-ear-plugin optional?
if packaging type is ear, then default will use maven-ear-plugin?

If the packaging is defined ear the maven-ear-plugin will be executed based on the life cyle (https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.9.8/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_ear_packaging) you should define the version of your plugin (maven-ear-plugin) via pluginManagement...  May you need to define the webModule separately... for example if the contextRoot differes from the default...

but why even I comment out the plugins section of maven-ear-plugin, everything seems still the same, and can build the ear successfully?

Yes of course that's I wrote ... because the life cycle binds that by default for packaging: ear... (seen reference to maven-core...

ok, I also see the statement "Some phases have goals bound to them by default. And for the default lifecycle, these bindings depend on the packaging value." in url https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference

If I comment out the plugins section of maven-ear-plugin, I see it is using maven-ear-plugin:2.8, how maven decide which version of maven-ear-plugin to use?

If the version of maven-ear-plugin is 2.8 than you are using ancient old Maven version... I strongly recommend to Upgrade your Maven version ?
